# Adding new record in Kendo grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a problem with saving new records in kendo grid. When I update the grid it works normally, when I try to add new records, it doesn't. When I try to investigate the problem in debugger, network, I got this during POST process (last qutation mark is missing):

```
{ "Comment": "","OrderType": "43434343","Amount": "0","Status": "0","_MaterialKey": "83000000000","StartTime": "Tue Jun 02 2015 10:43:17 GMT+0200 }
```

here is the part of my parameter map:

```
 transport: {
        read: {
          url: $("#gatewayPath").data("value") + "odata/ods/Plannings?$expand=Material($select=_Key,MaterialLocalName,MaterialGlobalName)&$select=_Key,OrderType,Amount,StartTime,Comment,Status",
          datatype: 'json',
          beforeSend: function (x) {
            var auth = $("#authenticationType").data("value") + " " + $("#authenticationToken").data("value");
            x.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
          }
        },

       if (operation === "create")  {
              return '{ "Comment": "' + ((!data.Comment) ? "" : data.Comment) +
                      '","OrderType": "' + ((!data.OrderType) ? "" : data.OrderType) +
                      '","Amount": "' + ((!data.Amount) ? "0" : data.Amount) +
                      '","Status": "' + ((!data.Status) ? 0 : data.Status) +
                      '","_MaterialKey": "' + ((!data.Material) ? "83000000000" : data.Material._Key) +
                      '","StartTime": "' + ((!data.StartTime) ? 0 : data.StartTime) +
                 ' }';
        }
        else if (operation === "update") {
          if (data._Kendo_SaveIt == 1) {
              data._Kendo_SaveIt = 0;
              return '{ "_Key": "' + data._Key +
                     '","StartTime": "' + kendoHelper.getDate(data.StartTime) +                 
                     '","OrderType": "' + data.OrderType +
                     '","Amount": "' + data.Amount +
                     ((data.Material) ? '","_MaterialKey": "' + data.Material._Key : "") +
                     '","Comment": "' + data.Comment +
                     '","Status": "' + data.Status +
                     '"}';
          }
        }



 create: {
        url: function (data) {
          return $("#gatewayPath").data("value") + "odata/ods/Plannings?$expand=Material($select=_Key,MaterialLocalName,MaterialGlobalName)&$select=_Key,OrderType,Amount,StartTime,Comment,Status";
        },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function (x) {
          var auth = $("#authenticationType").data("value") + " " + $("#authenticationToken").data("value");
          x.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
        }
      },
    update: {
      url: function (data) {
        return $("#gatewayPath").data("value") + "odata/ods/Plannings(" + data._Key + ")?$expand=Material($select=_Key,MaterialLocalName,MaterialGlobalName)&$select=_Key,OrderType,Amount,StartTime,Comment,Status";
      },
      dataType: "json",
      type: "PATCH",
      beforeSend: function (x) {
        var auth = $("#authenticationType").data("value") + " " + $("#authenticationToken").data("value");
        x.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
      }
    },
```

Comment: in Create Map look here and fix this                        '","StartTime": "' + ((!data.StartTime) ? 0 : data.StartTime) +
                 ' "}';    <--- Add " here ....and try

Comment: now I have quotation on the end but I got 400 bad request, still doesn't work :/

Comment: As mentioned by @VinitPatel you need to put a closing quotes, but you triggered another question. So, could you please post your kendo grid data-source transport options?

Comment: here it is, transport added

Comment: The problem is, you missed to specify both `create` and `update` configurations, like the one configured in `read`

Comment: i haven't, it is here, edited

Comment: The part of `if .. else` needs to be inside `parameterMap` function, see kendo [docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79405/discussion-between-mshaaban-and-dinone).